# Flux write tag in pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, flux

Right now I am getting this error.

[image]

[image]

I am getting this error when I set up flux with Terraform and also with command line. What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: What does your Gitlab CI pipeline look like? If it's really long can you try to find an [mcve] that reproduces your error?

Comment: image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  ## Set up Terraform 
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - mkdir -p ./creds
  - echo $SERVICEACCOUNT | base64 -d > ./creds/serviceaccount.json
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

Every stage just runs terraform command

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include that information please? Hard to read in an unformatted comment.